# Does NetBeans recognize JavaScript prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, netbeans

Does NetBeans recognize JavaScript prototypal inheritance? To me it seems that it does not:

Code:

```
function A() {} 
A.prototype.doSomething = function () {} 

function B() {} 
B.prototype = new A(); 

var test = new B(); 
test.
```

after typing the dot and pressing ctrl+space I do not see doSomething()-method, but everything in B is covered though (in this example nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans, being a Java IDE, does, indeed, not function fully with JS,

prototype inheritance being one of these things.

In fairness - I can't see this being a common or critical issue.

Comment: I would imagine any web developer to have a need for an IDE that works with JavaScript.

Comment: This is true. And as you may have noticed, NetBeans does. It should however be noted that other IDEs such as WebStorm fails to perform this action too, and, as mentioned, this isn't a good way to code JS in either case.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008/2010 supports this; its code completion for JavaScript is pretty advanced in general.
This might not be an option for you (there's a free edition, but you might not even be using Windows), but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: are you implying that there is a way to write inheritance in JavaScript that NetBeans can understand?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes - Keep it on one level. No, because you can only stick to one level. On ONE had; I have a few years under my belt in JS coding without ever using more than one level of prototyping. And there is usually a much better way to do it. On the OTHER hand - NetBeans is buggy. :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does (at least 7.0 beta2)! You have to use prototype.js syntax for extending classes, but you can hide it in if (false) conditional, so you don't need the prototype.js actually...

Your example will look like:

```
function A() {} 
A.prototype.doSomething = function () {} 

function B() {} 
B.prototype = new A(); 
// here is the magic trick
if (false) var B = Class.create(A, {});

var test = new B();
```

You can use any of these:

- `var B = Class.create(A, {})`
- `var B = Object.extend(new A(), {});`

As a side note, the whole DOM is built around class-like inheritance, so it's rather important for IDEs to properly support it!